# Records created in Rspec aren't available in new threads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, rspec

In Rspec, I'm creating records, e.g. `let!(:user) { create(:user) }`.

I can access the new user in Rspec and in the main thread of the subject. Both of these return the user:

```
puts User.all.to_a
puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('select * from users')
```

However, I can now longer access the user in a new thread:

```
Thread.new do
    puts User.all.to_a
    puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('select * from users')
end
```

How do I fix this? Is this just an Rspec issue? I don't think I can reproduce it in Rails console.

Comment: We would need to see the entire test, Are you sure the user is created before you run that thread?

Comment: Are you sure the thread is connecting to the same database? Check `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably configured RSpec to run its test within a database transaction

Quote from the [RSpec Docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions):
>

> When you run `rails generate rspec:install`, the `spec/rails_helper.rb` file
>   includes the following configuration:
>
> ```
> RSpec.configure do |config|
>   config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
> end
> ```
>
> The name of this setting is a bit misleading. What it really means in Rails
>   is "run every test method within a transaction." In the context of rspec-rails,
>   it means "run every example within a transaction."
>
> The idea is to start each example with a clean database, create whatever data
>   is necessary for that example, and then remove that data by simply rolling back
>   the transaction at the end of the example.

You might want to disable this configuration when your application tests have the requirement to support multiple threads at the same time.

But that means that your test database will not be cleared from test data automatically anymore when a test is done. Instead, you will need to delete the test data manually or use another gem (like [`database_cleaner`](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner)) to reset the database after running tests.